# Installing pysystemtrade in Anaconda3

Tags: python, git

I have Anaconda3 installed on my Windows 10 computer. I want to install the pysystemtrade package from GitHub. This is the instructions from the author

"This package isn't hosted on pip. So to get the code the easiest way is to use git:

git clone https://github.com/robcarver17/pysystemtrade.git
python3 setup.py develop"

The question is, where do I clone the project to and where do I run setup.py to get it installed in the correct place in Anaconda3 so I can include the files in my python project?

Thanks,
Dana

Answer (score 0):

Create a conda environment with the python version, switch to that environment to keep track of dependencies for that environment. Then clone the Git repo. Afterwards, install the requirements.txt for that Github project, and run the command he gave you to add that dependency to your conda environment.

```
conda create -n trade-test python=3.8  
conda activate trade-test 
git clone https://github.com/robcarver17/pysystemtrade.git
cd pysystemtrade/
pip3 install -r requirements.txt
python3 setup.py develop
```

Comment: Thanks. I did that and when I opened Spyder3 and tried to run one of his example code files it can't find any of the modules.

Comment: I am not that used to environments, so I found I needed to have Spyder installed in the new environment to get it to work. Now I am dealing with the new numpy error. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Great! Good luck. Sometimes it just takes a bit of patience.